# Using libclang/libtooling

Tags: c++, c, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

I have to retrieve all the structures and type defined in a project (as described in my previous question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23154414/c-project-get-all-global-variables-and-all-types" ).

I chose the clang solution because it seems to be my only way...
However, the only "good" tutorial I've found is this one : http://kevinaboos.wordpress.com/2013/07/23/clang-tutorial-part-i-introduction/ and there are still some questions remaining :

1) Are the pre-processor directives handled (#include, #define etc.)

2) How to retrieve the type, and the structure member ?

actually, for this * simple * code for example:

```
typedef struct
{
   int i;
   char i2;
} S1; 

typedef struct S2
{
   int i;
   struct S2 s2;
} S2;

typedef S3 struct S3;
struct S3
{
   int i;
   char i2;
}
S1 m_s1;
S2 m_s2;
struct S3 m_s3;
```

what method from an `clang::RecursiveASTVisitor`-derived class (http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1RecursiveASTVisitor.html) are called and in wich order ? (and could you give me explanations on how to retrieve the data I need ?)

Comment: Surely both of your questions could be answered by some experimenting. The detailed description in your link seems to explain quite well exactly what happens. If you don't understand how an abstract syntax tree works, then perhaps you should read up on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, as Mat Petersson Adviced, I experimented.

1) Yes, the AST is generated after the preprocessor. It permit to retrieve all the informations.

2) The AST traversal is depth-first. Rather than implement `VisitFoo(Foo *)` methods, you can reimplement `TraverseFoo(Foo *)` method to get the begin and the end of each node lookup :

```
class YourVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<YourVisitor>
{
   //...
   virtual bool TraverseFoo(Foo * f)
   {
      //Some stuff to do before to explore the children
      bool r = RecursiveASTVisitor<YourVisitor>::TraverseFoo(f);
      //Some stuff to do after
      return r
   }
}
```

Then to get the structs ( = records) and their members, just to re-implement TraverseRecordDecl to handle the struct and VisitFieldDecl to get the fields.